Export projected coordinate in ArcMap
I have some points with EPSG=4326. I saved it as EPSG=3824 and imported it into ArcMap again. Then I used Data Management Tool > Features > Add XY Coordinates to add x and y coordinates to the attribute data. However, it generates the coordinates with the original CRS(EPSG=4326). I have checked the Properties page, but it showed that the CRS of this shape file is 3824. How to figure it out?


I agree with @user2856, I think the source of your problem is that you saved your 4326 data as a 3824. If you are converting from one coordinate system to another you need to PROJECT the dataset, that applies the actual mathematical transformation to the data.

Disclosure: I work for Esri, focusing on coordinate reference systems and transformations.
EPSG::3824 is geographic 2D TWD 1997. We have only 1 geographic/datum transformation between TWD 1997 and WGS 84 (EPSG::4326). Its parameter values are zeroes, so, at least at some level, the two geoCRS are considered identical. You will not see any changes to the coordinate values, no matter how you exported the data.
EPSG notes that TWD97 (their name) is based on ITRF94 at epoch 1997.0.
There is a transformation between WGS 84 (G873) and ITRF94 at epoch 1997.0, EPSG::9876. All parameter values are zeroes.
